Vue3 Pinia State Management
When using Pinia in your ViewModel, are you allowed to combine the viewmodel's methods along with the pinia actions when using Pinia's mapActions and mapState wrappers? or do all methods and computed methods have to remain in the pinia store and then be referenced in the viewModel?
    computed: {
        ...mapState(useFilterStore, ['selectedItem', 'selectedOrderBy', 'selectedPageSize', 'toggle', 'toggleAdvFilter', 'view']),
        ...mapState(useCalendarStore, ['getCalendarByUser']),
        setting() { return Base.currentUser.CalendarSetting },
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(useCartStore, ['addToCart']),
        
        async SendRequest(form) { await new UserService().SendCalendarRequest(form); },
    

I've tried commenting out each mapState/mapAction and vice versa with the viewModel methods

yes, you can combine.  pinia actions can be used anywhere, while other methods/computeds are only usable locally in the component they're defined in.  is there a problem or error associated with your code?  You should edit the question with more information about what problem you're actually facing.  See How to Ask guide.

I get the green sqiggles to the defined methods, when I add the mapStates/mapActions. When I commet out the pinia mapStates/mapActions, the green sqiggles disappear. So I was wondering if that would be causing a problem that I am not seeing in the errors.

I'm not sure what green squiggles entails.  It's specific to your IDE.  probably hover your mouse over it for specific error or warning message and post it here.
